# Call a function with parameter in codeigniter using hyperlink

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I want to call controller function with parameter from hyperlink in view page.

Here is code of View:

```
<a href="<?php site_url("report_attendance/export_leave_data/".$result['leavetype_id'])?>" name="leavereport" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark pull-right" style="width: 100px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Export</a>
```

Controller's function:

```
function export_leave_data($leaveid) 
{

}
```

Here, when I saw in inspect element, it shows nothing in href. Like this,

```
<a style="width: 100px;margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark pull-right" name="leavereport" href="">Export</a>
```

So, actually where I am going wrong??

Comment: try this:<?php echo site_url("report_attendance/export_present_data/".$result['leavetype_id'])?>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing echo replace

```
<a href="<?php site_url("report_attendance/export_present_data/".$result['leavetype_id'])?>" name="leavereport" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark pull-right" style="width: 100px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Export</a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("report_attendance/export_present_data/".$result['leavetype_id'])?>" name="leavereport" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark pull-right" style="width: 100px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Export</a>
```

Comment: You are most welcome and for more on codeigniter you can visit  http://w3code.in/codeigniter/